# MySQL Workbench takes forever to run a SQL script of 2GB

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a .sql backup file that I want to run to recover my tables and data on my computer. I have MySQL Server 8.0 running on my laptop (on Windows 10), and I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0.

I ran my script using the 'Run SQL Script' functionality. After an entire night, it still was far from completion. My script has a size of 2.5 GB, I unfortunately can't open it from any text editors because they take too long. 
Is there a way to speed up this process? Thank you.

Comment: did you try to do it with programming (java,,python,C# ...)

Comment: What do you mean? I need to import this data in my mysql database, in order to be able to do queries on it.

Comment: you can do it with java, use jdbc driver and insert data

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running this dump (backup) file through the UI use the restore feature of MySQL Workbench, which is made particularly for this situation:

[image]